# Warning when comparing single char in C and more

Tags: c, char

In my code, there is a very simple if statement that asks user for consent for what the program will take very long to finish running because the user specified value is too high.

```c
int main() {
  char consent; // f around and find out preventer

  if (amount > AMOUNT_MAX) {
    printf("WARNING: %d exceeds AMOUNT_MAX. Continue?\n[Y]es or [N]o.");

    scanf("%c", &consent);

    if (consent == "Y") {
      quit(amount, "progname", true);
    } else {
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

These are the warnings I get:

```
quit.c:28:23: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat-insufficient-args]

   28 |     printf("WARNING: %d exceeds AMOUNT_MAX. Continue?\n[Y]es or [N]o.");

      |                      ~^

quit.c:30:17: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use an explicit string comparison function instead) [-Wstring-compare]

   30 |     if (consent == "Y") {

      |                 ^  ~~~

quit.c:30:17: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('char' and 'char *') [-Wpointer-integer-compare]

   30 |     if (consent == "Y") {

      |         ~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
```

Stack Overflow suggested me an existing solution to this problem but it didn't work for me.

EDIT: fixed it.

```c
int main() {
  char consent; // f around and find out preventer

  if (amount > AMOUNT_MAX) {
    printf("WARNING: %d exceeds AMOUNT_MAX. Continue?\n[Y]es or [N]o.", amount); // added data argument

    scanf("%c", &consent);

    if (consent == 'Y') { // changed to single quote
      quit(amount, "progname", true);
    } else {
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `consent == "Y"` here you compare `char` and `char *` (value of `concent` and address of string constant `"Y"`). Fix: `consent == 'Y'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A char is between single quotes in C!**

I made some slight changes to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define AMOUNT_MAX 5

int main() {
  char consent; // f around and find out preventer
  int amount = 6;
  if (amount > AMOUNT_MAX) {
    printf("WARNING: %d exceeds AMOUNT_MAX. Continue?\n[Y]es or [N]o.", amount);

    scanf("%c", &consent);

    if (consent == 'Y') {
      printf("progname");
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```